# Adding ActionBar in HTML pages using PhoneGap in android

Tags: android, cordova, android-actionbar

I am new to PhoneGap. I am using it to deploy my website on android phone. So I created www folder in assets folder and put all my HTML, CSS an js file and written this code to call the index.html page

```
import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;


public class HelloPhoneGapActivity extends DroidGap  {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
}
}
```

Every thing is working fine but now I have to add Action Bar with close button on every page. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: What do you want with this action bar and close button?... To close the application?

Comment: yes because when I navigate through the html pages I have to press back button multiple times to get out of the application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `navigator.app.exitApp();` to exit the application. Either do it on the click of a button or override the back key.

**UPDATE:**

Create a listener like this

> document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackClickEvent, true);

Then in the onBackClickEvent() write this

```
function onBackClickEvent() {
    navigator.app.exitApp();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I was unable to solve my problem. I am not able to override onBackPressed() and call navigator.app.exitApp();

Comment: What version of phonegap you using?

Comment: latest version i.e phonegap 1.5

Comment: Check out the update.If this is what you dont want then show me your approach....

Comment: Where should I need to write this code ? Inside HelloPhoneGapActivity or inside the html pages.

Comment: Obviously inside the .html page in which you are currently present... Then only you will be able to override the back key....

Comment: Is there not a way to add Action Bar in the page and show some buttons on it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9176/discussion-between-coder-slay-and-nishant)